# Not Able To Access MS SQL Folder so I can Access Backup Folder

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to access the backup files folder in order to restore the worldwideimporters bak file on my version of MS SQL Server, but I cannot.

In this image, there's supposed to be a folder named "MS SQL14.MSSQL Server" that contains the backup folders where I need to put the bak file in, but it's not there.

No MS SQL14.MSSQL Server folder no backup folder

[image: 1]

I'm expecting the MS SQL14.MSSQL Server folder to be there, and the backup folder to be in it.

Comment: Probably you are looking it under Program Files (x86). Try looking under Program Files instead.

Answer (score 0):

On a 64 bits windows its location is:

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL14.MSSQLSERVER
```

Note: You don't need to put a .bak file to the backup folder in order to be able to restore it.